# LazyInitializationException after return updated entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have some model with two relations:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_model")
public class DataModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "model_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataModel", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<OutputField> outputFields;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "dataModel", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Query> queries;

    //some another fields
}
```

I use `Spring Data JPA` and I want to update entity. I write simple service:

```java
@Service
public class DataModelService {

    @Autowired
    private DataModelRepository dataModelRepository;

    @Transactional
    public DataModel createOrUpdate(DataModel dataModel) {
       return dataModelRepository.save(dataModel);
    }

    //another methods
}
```

I write simple test:

```java
public class DataModelServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private DataModelService dataModelService;

    @Test
    void shouldUpdateDataModel() {
       DataModel dataModelBeforeUpdate = dataModelService.getById(1);
       dataModelBeforeUpdate.getQueries().get(0).setSqlQuery("SELECT 1");
       DataModel updatedModel = dataModelService.createOrUpdate(dataModelBeforeUpdate);
       assertThat(updatedModel.getQueries(), notNullValue());
    }
}
```

But, I get error, when I try to call method `getQieries()`:

```
Unable to evaluate the expression Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.
```

In debug I see:
[image]

Questions:

1. Why does this error occur and how can I fix it? How do I make hibernate return all links after an update?
2. Why is the `outputFields` field filled in correctly, but the `queries` field is not?

Comment: try `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` attribute with queries

Comment: This is not the solution! This is bad practice. However, why is `outputFileds` displayed normally when loading lazily?

Answer (score -1):

It happens because you are trying to initialize collection outside a transaction. To fix this add `@DataJpaTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotations to your test class. By default, data JPA tests are transactional.

Refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test) for more details.

Comment: What if I call this method from the controller? I will also get this error! This is not a solution. It also doesn't explain why `outputFields` are initialized

Comment: Generally it's not a good idea to return an entity from service. You should map your entity to dto inside the service using for example https://mapstruct.org/.

Comment: By default `@OneToMany` relation fetch type is `Lazy`. It means that a collection is loading from database only when you are getting it 's elements. It could not be loaded outside a transaction. Another way to fix this exception is to call `Hibernate.initialize(savedDataModel.getQueries())` before returning from service method.

Comment: I know this and already use `mapstruct` at the controller level. I just can't figure out what it depends on that hibernate fills `outputFields`, even though they are lazy and queries aren't? This is magic for me

Comment: I think it's because `outputFields` are not changed. Better use mapping inside a service and not inside the controller